# Why I am Getting this error? : Attribute 'data-role' is not a valid attribute of element 'li'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-3.5

Hope you all are doing well.

I am developing a Meeting Room Reservation System in Visual Studio 2008.

In this I am trying to use Metro UI Drop down

I have added the Css and Javascript file

But I am getting error in JS due to following Error

[image]

Thanks In Advance

[image]

I am Getting this Error in JS

Comment: That doesn't look like a JS error to me, but `data-role` is indeed not valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional.  Try validating against HTML5

Comment: `Data-*` is html5 compatible.

Comment: the JS error has nothing to do with the warning you are passing null as the argument for $

Comment: element li is getting recognized by its data-role in js, the data-role is not a valid attribute that is why this error is occuring

Comment: No, as @RuneFS said, the errors are unrelated. It looks like you're missing components in your jQuery deployment. Where is `$.fn` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS error states that `$ === null` this is unrelated to the HTML and a result of passing null as the argument to `function($)` the most likely cause for this error is that the script you are showing a picture of is included prior to including jQuery in the page

Comment: @ Rune FS : I have added JQuery to my page but still getting js error.

Comment: @FahadHussain but have you added it prior to the script that fails? and are you passing in the correct object as a parameter?

Answer (score 4):

The `data-*` attributes were introduced in HTML5. It looks like you're running Visual Studio 2008 in XHTML1.0 Transitional mode. VS2008 does not provide validation support for HTML5, seeming as VS2008 predates the first working-draft of HTML5 by about 4 months.

It isn't an error, it's a warning; however it is completely benign and can be safely ignored.

VS's validation files are extensible (they're *.xsd files), however they didn't anticipate freeform attributes like `data-foo=""`, so there is no way to get VS to ignore this class of warning, just grin and bear it.